# Generating huge report

Tags: django, database

I have this problem when I generate a report for a huge database. My application is in django and when I hit this report which generates report from a huge database, it consumes lots of memory and CPU for a very long time. However, once the report generation is finished it still does not release memory and as a result my server shows some issues. Actually, I haven't used any sort of filters to limit the number of records that are fetched. So it fetches all the records and tries to generate a report. This definitely consumes lots of memory and CPU.  Any suggestions?

Comment: we need more specifics, what query?, how many row's is it returning? some code of your report generation would help. use django-debug-toolbar to find out how much time is it taking to execute the query.

Comment: Actually, I don't have problems with the CPU time and memory it is consuming since there is huge amount of data. But once it was finished it should have released the memory. I am using memcached. Could it be the problem because of that? I mean when I first ran the report then all the data is cached in memcached. It's ok. However when I run the same report again, it should not have allocated extra memory isn't it, it should have used the data from memcached cache isn't it. The memory consumption keeps on increasing. That's the problem. Suggestions?

Comment: You don't have DEBUG set to True, do you?

Comment: Need some more suggestions. Since my database is huge. Is it better to archive the records based upon year and keep the database light. I mean I could archive records for each year. Will that be a better solution? But what if the end user wants the old data. I can't tell him to go through the archives. I might need another application I guess. Suggestions?

Comment: If your hosting on linux, are you using mod_python with apache?

Comment: yes I am using mod_python with apache

Answer (score 2):

Please consider using `mod_wsgi` instead of `mod_python`. `mod_python` creates the python interpreter inside the the apache process. This might lead to hoarding of large amount of memory. Its easier to host on mod_wsgi, have a look at [django on apache with mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/).  Another cause could be you have declared global variables and assigned it to the huge report data, this prevents python garbage collector from releasing the memory. consider reducing the data set by applying some `filters`, consider reporting with date constraint. Clear the cache since the data set is huge the garbage collector might not have released it.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing normal process behaviour in operation. When memory is allocated by a process it doesn't normally get released back to the operating system and when free only gets returned to the free list of the actual process. There are some exceptions to this for some memory allocators and newer versions of Python whereby if a contiguous block of memory at the top of the memory space gets freed, it can be returned to the operating system and therefore doesn't count against the process any more. This is the exception though.

You are probably better off executing the memory expensive operation in a separate process that can be killed off on completion.